# python script that runs in pycharm has memory allocation error when running from command line

Tags: python, tensorflow, terminal, pycharm, multiprocessing

I have a script to train a CNN, with keras over tensorflow 2.0.0, it works great when I use pycharm, 
But when I run it from the comment line (python train.py) it crashes because of allocation issues:
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sN9wI.png)
I tried workers=1 and use_multiprocessing=False is the fit_generator, it didn't help.
Any idea of why this is happening? what happens in pycharm that is missing in the terminal?

I’m running on NVIDIA tf 2.0.0 docker container.

Comment: Could you confirm that you have the same python interpreter set up in both your shell and your PyCharm IDE? To check in the shell do : `python --version`, for PyCharm you can look into the Preferences menu.

Answer (score 0):

If by 'command line' you mean running in docker, your tf container doesn't have access to your entire machine RAM like pycharm would. Do `docker info` have a look at the memory, adjust to how much is needed using tips from here https://dzone.com/articles/docker-container-resource-management-cpu-ram-and-i

Comment: thanks from the comment, I use pycharm remote interpreter to run the script on the same container